# Can slerp function in unity make the figure walk strange circles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to lean unity with following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmGSEH7QcDg&t=30084s

at 1:22:30, the teacher wants to make the player figure rotate to the walking direction and adds following code:
`transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);`

As I added it, my player started to walk in weird circles by pressing a direction key.

Here my full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
  private void Update() {
        Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(0, 0);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            inputVector.y = +1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            inputVector.y = -1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            inputVector.x = -1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            inputVector.x = +1;
        }



        inputVector = inputVector.normalized;

        Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
        transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        //float rotateSpeed = 10f; //1:22:36
        //transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
        float rotateSpeed = 10f;
        transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You are moving the play to either x or y = -1 or +1 .  Don't you want to change direction by multiplying movDir by -1?

Comment: What do you mean strange circles .. if you rotate very slow then well yes you will be moving on a circle like a car which has a certain maximum speed by which it applies a direction change ... If your teacher does stuff .. why not ask your teacher  about it? supposed to teach you after all ;)

Comment: @derHugo it's not a real teacher, it's CodeMonkey, a Unity tutorial YT channel. He didn't mean it literally.

Comment: @Felix Gruen do you have a video showing us what happens? I assume you made a 3D project.

Comment: @TheNomad same argument stands though ;)

Comment: @derHugo He stated quite clearly what the player should do (turn in the direction he is moving) and that instead the movement changes.

Answer (score 1):

---

PlayerVisual's center of rotation is not correct.
Make sure the position of PlayerVisual component is (0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. Finally I found the reason: my player and playervisual were not at the same place, after changed their postions to (0,0,0) it worked.